# Read statement fails as internal table is empty

Tags: abap

Recently I've come across a Read statement which gives **Sy-subrc** eq 8. this happens because the internal table has no records and at the same time  variables in the **WHERE** clause are empty too. What I have been wondering is why wouldn't we check if the table **is not initial** before the read statement?

pleas let me know if we can check the itab is not initial before read statement.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: `why wouldn't we check if the table is not initial before the read statement?` ask this those noob who wrote those clumsy code :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check `itab` `is not initial` before read statement. what's bothering you? it's not an issue. And **WITH KEY** or **WITH TABLE KEY** clause used with read statement not **WHERE**.
And if there is no value exist in internal table for given key value then **`SY-SUBRC`** will be **4**

Answer (score 1):

It's a wrong assumption to make a direct link between `READ TABLE` on an empty table and `SY-SUBRC = 8`. If you read the official [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapread_table.htm), you will see that `SY-SUBRC = 8` is related to the variant `READ TABLE ... BINARY SEARCH`.

So, with `READ TABLE ... BINARY SEARCH`, `SY-SUBRC` will be 8 if the searched line doesn't exist but if it was inserted it would be placed after the last line of the table. Of course, that's always the case when the internal table is empty.

Addendum May, 10th: SY-SUBRC = 8 may also occur with READ TABLE on internal tables of type SORTED (because it's using a binary search implicitly).

Comment: Good to see someone else is providing links to the documentation while I'm too busy doing other things :-)